# How to execute a python macro that launches another python script?

Tags: python, macros, libreoffice

I want to create a python macro on libreoffice which will trigger another python script. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know why.

When I launch the python from terminal it works fine but not from macro.

My macro.py file :

```
import os

def launch():
        os.system("python /home/ivq/Documents/generation.py")
launch()
```

Expected result : launch generation.py
Actual result : nothing happen

Comment: How do you know if its not getting launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["python", "/home/ivq/Documents/generation.py"])
```

Should help?